# combining to columns as dict in new column Pandas - Value Error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to generate a report from but seem to be getting errors that I can't figure out how to fix. Here is my dataframe

```
   Unnamed: 0 COMPANY      rNAME DATE_START DATEFINISH       tID     LABEL
0           0     MOM  11 UNIT A   8/9/2021  8/23/2021  36350000   UNIT 5H
1           1     MOM   7 UNIT A   8/9/2021  8/23/2021  36350000   UNIT 5H
2           2     DAD       7H A   7/7/2021  7/27/2021  36350000   UNIT 5H
3           3     MOM  13 UNIT A   8/9/2021  8/23/2021  36350000   UNIT 5H
4           4     MOM   9 UNIT A   8/9/2021  8/23/2021  36350000   UNIT 5H
5           5     DAD       4H A   7/7/2021  7/27/2021  36350000   UNIT 5H
6           6     DAD       8H A   7/7/2021  7/27/2021  27690000   UNIT 2H
7           7     DAD       5H A   7/7/2021  7/27/2021  27690000   UNIT 2H
8           8     DAD       7H A   7/7/2021  7/27/2021  27690000   UNIT 2H
9           9     DAD       4H A   7/7/2021  7/27/2021  27690000   UNIT 2H
```

Then the code I am getting the errors on is

```
jdata = df.groupby(["COMPANY", "rNAME","DATE_START", "DATEFINISH"], as_index=False) \
    .apply(lambda x: x[['tID','LABEL']].to_dict('r')).reset_index().rename(columns={0: "MDATA"}).to_json(orient='records')
```

Then what I want to do with my result is

```
jsonObject = json.loads(jdata)

for i in jsonObject:
    print (i[COMPANY])
    print (i[rNAME])
    print (i[DATE_START])
    print (i[DATEFINISH])
    for p in i["MDATA"]:
        print (p[tID])
```

The error I'm getting is

```
ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns
```

Which I know has to do with the dict, but I'm unsure how to fix this

I also believe it has to do with the data, sometimes when I receive data it works fine, other times I get the x columns passed error.

I have looked on here for several days and haven't found a solution to my issue of creating a dict column from two other columns causing an error like this

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: what i have shown in what I want to do after. I want to show all tID's that are under Company, rname, grouping, will be impacted during the date start and end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like what you’re doing slightly tweaked:

1. get a series of list of dictionaries (i.e. no `as_index=False`)

   - you can also specify the columns on the groupby directly
2. rename the series and reset index to obtain all data
3. transform to json

```
>>> dicts = df.groupby(['COMPANY', 'rNAME', 'DATE_START', 'DATEFINISH'])[['tID','LABEL']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
>>> dicts
COMPANY  rNAME      DATE_START  DATEFINISH
DAD      4H A       7/7/2021    7/27/2021     [{'tID': 36350000, 'LABEL': 'UNIT 5H'}, {'tID'...
         5H A       7/7/2021    7/27/2021               [{'tID': 27690000, 'LABEL': 'UNIT 2H'}]
         7H A       7/7/2021    7/27/2021     [{'tID': 36350000, 'LABEL': 'UNIT 5H'}, {'tID'...
         8H A       7/7/2021    7/27/2021               [{'tID': 27690000, 'LABEL': 'UNIT 2H'}]
MOM      11 UNIT A  8/9/2021    8/23/2021               [{'tID': 36350000, 'LABEL': 'UNIT 5H'}]
         13 UNIT A  8/9/2021    8/23/2021               [{'tID': 36350000, 'LABEL': 'UNIT 5H'}]
         7 UNIT A   8/9/2021    8/23/2021               [{'tID': 36350000, 'LABEL': 'UNIT 5H'}]
         9 UNIT A   8/9/2021    8/23/2021               [{'tID': 36350000, 'LABEL': 'UNIT 5H'}]
dtype: object
>>> jdata = dicts.rename('MDATA').reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
```

If you pass `indent=True` to `to_json()` here’s what the output looks like:

```
>>> print(jdata[:500])
[
 {
  "COMPANY":"DAD",
  "rNAME":"4H A",
  "DATE_START":"7\/7\/2021",
  "DATEFINISH":"7\/27\/2021",
  "MDATA":[
   {
    "tID":36350000,
    "LABEL":"UNIT 5H"
   },
   {
    "tID":27690000,
    "LABEL":"UNIT 2H"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "COMPANY":"DAD",
  "rNAME":"5H A",
  "DATE_START":"7\/7\/2021",
  "DATEFINISH":"7\/27\/2021",
  "MDATA":[
   {
    "tID":27690000,
    "LABEL":"UNIT 2H"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "COMPANY":"DAD",
  "rNAME":"7H A",
  "DATE_START":"7\/7\/2021",
  "DATEFINISH":"7\/27\/2021",
  "M
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `groupby` without using `as_index=False`:

```
jdata = df.groupby(["COMPANY", "rNAME","DATE_START", "DATEFINISH"])['tID','LABEL'] \
          .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')) \ 
          .reset_index(name="MDATA") \
          .to_dict(orient='records')

for i in jdata:
    for key in ["COMPANY", "rNAME", "DATE_START", "DATEFINISH"]:
        print(i[key], end=" ")
    for p in i["MDATA"]:
        print(p["tID"], end=" ")
    print()

DAD 4H A 7/7/2021 7/27/2021 36350000 27690000 
DAD 5H A 7/7/2021 7/27/2021 27690000 
DAD 7H A 7/7/2021 7/27/2021 36350000 27690000 
DAD 8H A 7/7/2021 7/27/2021 27690000 
MOM 11 UNIT A 8/9/2021 8/23/2021 36350000 
MOM 13 UNIT A 8/9/2021 8/23/2021 36350000 
MOM 7 UNIT A 8/9/2021 8/23/2021 36350000 
MOM 9 UNIT A 8/9/2021 8/23/2021 36350000
```

Other changes to your code:

- Specify the columns to use in the `groupby` statement
- Rename the resulting column within `reset_index`
- Directly convert to `dict` instead of json

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked as well, but i could only mark one as the solution